# all Fragment recreating when a switching through fragments using tablayout

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmentmanager

I am creating an application which is based on Tabs using tablayout. I **didn't use viewpager**. My logic is that users can create fragments (Tabs) like adding tabs in chrome so that whenever user clicks add button a new tab is created with a fragment. Now i need to save unique time stamp of each fragment created time in shared preference so that whenever i move to one fragment i can use that shared reference timestamp value to do unique function intended for that particular fragment.

But i don't know where to save that timestamp. I tried to get the time in milliseconds in Oncreate function of Fragment but whenever I switch between tabs everytime the onCreate call so that each time i switch between tabs the shared preference value changes as i added it in onCreate in Fragments.

My Logic is that it should only create once a fragment is created when user clicks add and must be able to use that in fragments.

As every time i switch to other fragement it just reinitilize all view and onCreate in called. so i could not set timestamp in oncreate..

Please help me

my Activity code is:

```
public class TabActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
    public static TabActivity instance;
    private FragmentChild fragmentOne;

    private TabLayout allTabs;
    ImageView add;
    ImageView imageButtonAdd2;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.tab_activity);

        getAllWidgets();
        bindWidgetsWithAnEvent();
        setupTabLayout();

    }
    public static TabActivity getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }
    private void getAllWidgets() {
        allTabs = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.simpleTabLayout);
        add = findViewById(R.id.addButton);
        imageButtonAdd2 = findViewById(R.id.imageButtonAdd2);
    }
    private void setupTabLayout() {
        allTabs.addTab(allTabs.newTab().setText("ONE"),true);
        add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                allTabs.addTab(allTabs.newTab().setText("NEW_TAB"),true);
                bindWidgetsWithAnEvent();
            }
        });
        imageButtonAdd2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                /*Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putString("data", String.valueOf(0));
                fragmentSecond = new SecondFragment();
                fragmentSecond.setArguments(bundle);
                replaceFragment(fragmentSecond,"SecondFragment");*/
            }
        });
    }
    private void bindWidgetsWithAnEvent()
    {
        allTabs.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                setCurrentTabFragment(tab.getPosition());
            }
            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            }
            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            }
        });
    }
    private void setCurrentTabFragment(int tabPosition)
    {
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("data", String.valueOf(tabPosition));
        fragmentOne = new FragmentChild();
        fragmentOne.setArguments(bundle);
        replaceFragment(fragmentOne,"FirstFragment");
    }
    public void replaceFragment(Fragment fragment, String fragmentName) {
        long time= System.currentTimeMillis();
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.simpleFrameLayout, fragment,fragmentName);
        //ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
        ft.commit();
    }
    public void backStackFragment(Fragment fragment, String fragmentName) {
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.simpleFrameLayout, fragment,fragmentName);
        ft.addToBackStack(null);
        //ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
        ft.commit();
    }
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed(){
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        if (fm.getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
            Log.i("MainActivity", "popping backstack");
            fm.popBackStack();
        } else {
            Log.i("MainActivity", "nothing on backstack, calling super");
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
}
```

FragmentChild class:

```
public class FragmentChild extends Fragment {
    String childname;
    TextView textViewChildName;
    EditText editText;
    private GridView mGridView;
    private ListItem mListItem;
    private ListView mListview;
    private ProgressBar mProgressBar;
    private ProductViewAdapter mGridAdapter;
    private ListViewAdapter mListAdapter = null;
    private ArrayList<GridItem> mGridData;
    private ArrayList<ListItem> mListData = null;
    ListView listView;
    CheckInterNetConnection check ;
    Boolean isInternetPresent = false;
    PreferenceHelper prefs;
    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private ViewPagerAdapter adapter;
    public static ViewPager viewPager;
    String posid = "";
    int page =0;
    String title  = "";
    TabLayout allTabs;
    int tab_position = 0;
    long time=0;
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //GlobalBus.getBus().register(this);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_child, container, false);
        Bundle bundle = getArguments();
        childname = bundle.getString("data");
        Log.e("onCreateView","onCreateView");
        getIDs(view);
        setEvents();
        return view;
    }


    // Store instance variables based on arguments passed
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setRetainInstance(true);
         time= System.currentTimeMillis();
        page = getArguments().getInt("someInt", 0);
        title = getArguments().getString("someTitle");
        Log.e("onCreate","onCreate");
    }
    private void getIDs(View view) {
        //textViewChildName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textViewChild);
        //textViewChildName.setText(childname);
        //editText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editText);
        //editText.setText("");
    }

    private void setEvents() {

    }
    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        Log.e("onViewCreated","onViewCreated");

    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        // Unregister the registered event.
        EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
    }
    public static FragmentChild newInstance(int page, String title) {
        FragmentChild fragmentFirst = new FragmentChild();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt("someInt", page);
        args.putString("someTitle", title);
        fragmentFirst.setArguments(args);
        return fragmentFirst;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        Log.e("onActivityCreated","onActivityCreated");
        allTabs = (TabLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.simpleTabLayout);
        mGridView = (GridView) getView().findViewById(R.id.gridView);
        prefs = new PreferenceHelper(getActivity());
        mGridData = new ArrayList<>();
        mGridAdapter = new ProductViewAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.grid_product_layout, mGridData);
        mGridView.setAdapter(mGridAdapter);

        mListview = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.list);
        mListData = new ArrayList<>();
        mListAdapter = new ListViewAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.list_row, mListData);
        mListview.setAdapter(mListAdapter);
        adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager(), getActivity(), viewPager, tabLayout);
    }
    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        Log.e("onStart","onStart");
        EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
        tab_position=allTabs.getSelectedTabPosition();
        //Log.e("TAB ID",String.valueOf(tab_position));
        prefs.save(String.valueOf(tab_position),"tab-"+time);
        check = new CheckInterNetConnection(getActivity());
        isInternetPresent = check.isConnectingToInternet();
        if (isInternetPresent) {
            fetchProducts(tab_position);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Log.e("onResume","onResume");
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
        Log.e("onPause","onPause");
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Subscribe
    public void onEvent(GlobalBus event){
        posid = event.getMessage();
        //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), event.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    public void fetchProducts(int tabPosition){
        String tabid = prefs.getString(String.valueOf(tabPosition),"0");
        Fragment fragment = getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.simpleFrameLayout);
        String tag = (String) fragment.getTag();
        //Log.e("URL","http://35.184.41.163/phpmyadmin/app/demo/products.php?tabid="+tabid+"&tab_position="+tabPosition);
        RestClientHelper.getInstance().get("http://35.184.41.163/phpmyadmin/app/demo/products.php", new RestClientHelper.RestClientListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(String response) {
                parseResult(response);
                mGridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
                        try {
                            ListItem items;
                            GridItem item = (GridItem) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                            items = new ListItem();
                            items.setName(item.getTitle());
                            items.setType(item.getDescription());
                            mListData.add(items);
                        }
                        catch(Exception e){

                        }
                        finally {
                            mListAdapter.setGridData(mListData);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(String error) {

            }
        });
    }

    private void parseResult(String result) {
        try {
            JSONObject response = new JSONObject(result);
            JSONArray posts = response.optJSONArray("products");
            GridItem item;
            if(posts.length() <= 0){
                RelativeLayout ly = (RelativeLayout) getView().findViewById(R.id.noOps);
                ly.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            else {
               // RelativeLayout ly = (RelativeLayout)  getView().findViewById(R.id.noOps);
                //ly.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                mGridData.clear();
                mGridAdapter.setGridData(mGridData);
                for (int i = 0; i < posts.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject post = posts.optJSONObject(i);
                    String id = post.optString("id");
                    String title = post.optString("name");
                    String description = post.optString("description");
                    String image = post.optString("image");
                    String qty = post.optString("qty");
                    String quantityin = post.optString("quantityin");
                    String price = post.optString("price");

                    item = new GridItem();
                    item.setId(id);
                    item.setTitle(title);
                    item.setDescription(description);
                    item.setImage(image);
                    item.setQuantity(qty);
                    item.setQuantityIn(quantityin);
                    item.setUnitprice(price);
                    mGridData.add(item);
                }
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally {
            mGridAdapter.setGridData(mGridData);
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE** as suggested by @Larry Hsiao

```
public class TabActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
    public static TabActivity instance;
    private FragmentChild fragmentOne;
    PreferenceHelper prefs;
    private TabLayout allTabs;
    ImageView add;
    ImageView imageButtonAdd2;
    private final List<Fragment> fragments = new ArrayList<>(); // maintain the instance for switching
    private int currentIndex = 0;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.tab_activity);
        prefs = new PreferenceHelper(TabActivity.this);
        getAllWidgets();
        //bindWidgetsWithAnEvent();
        setupTabLayout();
        bindWidgetsWithAnEvent();

    }
    public static TabActivity getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }
    private void getAllWidgets() {
        allTabs = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.simpleTabLayout);
        add = findViewById(R.id.addButton);
        add.performClick();
        imageButtonAdd2 = findViewById(R.id.imageButtonAdd2);
    }
    private void setupTabLayout() {
        int locfirst = allTabs.getSelectedTabPosition();
        locfirst = locfirst+1;
        allTabs.addTab(allTabs.newTab().setText("TAB"+locfirst),true);
        /*long time= System.currentTimeMillis();
        prefs.save("tab_"+locfirst,"tab_"+time);*/
        fragments.add(newFragment(0));
        addFragment(fragments.get(0));
        add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int loc = allTabs.getSelectedTabPosition();
                loc = loc+1;
                allTabs.addTab(allTabs.newTab().setText("TAB"+loc),true);
                fragments.add(newFragment(loc));
                addFragment(fragments.get(loc));
                /*bindWidgetsWithAnEvent();
                long time= System.currentTimeMillis();
                prefs.save("tab_"+loc,"tab_"+time);*/
            }
        });
        imageButtonAdd2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                /*Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putString("data", String.valueOf(0));
                fragmentSecond = new SecondFragment();
                fragmentSecond.setArguments(bundle);
                replaceFragment(fragmentSecond,"SecondFragment");*/
            }
        });
    }

    private Fragment newFragment(int position) {
        Fragment fragment = new FragmentChild();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("position", String.valueOf(position));
        fragment.setArguments(bundle);
        return fragment;
    }


    private void addFragment(Fragment fragment) {
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.add(R.id.simpleFrameLayout, fragment);
        transaction.commit();
    }

    private void changingTab(Fragment fragment) {
        FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
        transaction.hide(fragments.get(currentIndex));
        if (manager.getFragments().contains(fragment)) {
            transaction.show(fragment);
        }else {
            transaction.add(R.id.simpleFrameLayout,fragment);
        }
        transaction.commit();
    }

    private void bindWidgetsWithAnEvent()
    {
        allTabs.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                int nextPageIndex = (currentIndex + 1) % 2; // only two fragment switching
                changingTab(fragments.get(nextPageIndex));
                currentIndex = nextPageIndex;
                //setCurrentTabFragment(tab.getPosition());
            }
            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            }
            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            }
        });
    }
    \
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed(){
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        if (fm.getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
            Log.i("MainActivity", "popping backstack");
            fm.popBackStack();
        } else {
            Log.i("MainActivity", "nothing on backstack, calling super");
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
}
```

This force closes with this error:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                 Process: com.eazypos.app, PID: 13624
                                                                 java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 1, size is 1
                                                                     at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
                                                                     at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
                                                                     at com.eazypos.app.TabActivity$3.onTabSelected(TabActivity.java:115)
                                                                     at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.dispatchTabSelected(TabLayout.java:1165)
                                                                     at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.selectTab(TabLayout.java:1158)
                                                                     at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.selectTab(TabLayout.java:1128)
                                                                     at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout$Tab.select(TabLayout.java:1427)
                                                                     at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.addTab(TabLayout.java:483)
                                                                     at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.addTab(TabLayout.java:465)
                                                                     at com.eazypos.app.TabActivity$1.onClick(TabActivity.java:62)
                                                                     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
                                                                     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
                                                                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
```

**REMOVE TAB FUNCTION**

```
public void removeTab(int position) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "REMOVING --> "+position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        prefs.remove("tab_"+position);
        if (allTabs.getChildCount() > 0) {
            allTabs.removeTabAt(position);

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should maintain the Fragment instance which you already create. (With FragmentManager or just keep it with variable might do the job)

The method setCurrentTabFragment() in Activity which creating new Fragment is invoked every time user click tab. As the result, fragment always run through the onCreate()

```
// this method invoke every time user click the tab
private void setCurrentTabFragment(int tabPosition){
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("data", String.valueOf(tabPosition));
    fragmentOne = new FragmentChild(); // creating new Fragment
    fragmentOne.setArguments(bundle);
    replaceFragment(fragmentOne,"FirstFragment");
}
```

**Edited:**

- Use List to maintain the Fragment instance we already create.
- Switch Fragment with hide()/show() provided by FragmentManager, using add() if the Fragment not added to FragmentManager before.

Sample Code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private final List<Fragment> fragments = new ArrayList<>();
    private int currentIndex = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final TabLayout tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);

        // initial with one page
        Fragment firstFragment = newFragment(0);
        fragments.add(firstFragment);
        addFragment(firstFragment);
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Initial tab"));

        // user events
        findViewById(R.id.main_createTab).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                fragments.add(newFragment(tabLayout.getTabCount()));
                tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Pages " + tabLayout.getTabCount()));
            }
        });

        tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                int nextPageIndex = tab.getPosition();
                if (currentIndex == nextPageIndex){
                    return;
                }
                changingTab(fragments.get(nextPageIndex));
                currentIndex = nextPageIndex;
            }
            @Override public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {}
            @Override public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {}
        });
    }

    private Fragment newFragment(int position) {
        Fragment fragment = new FragmentWithLog();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("position", String.valueOf(position));
        fragment.setArguments(bundle);
        return fragment;
    }

    private void addFragment(Fragment fragment) {
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.add(R.id.main_fragmentFrame, fragment);
        transaction.commit();
    }

    private void changingTab(Fragment fragment) {
        FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
        transaction.hide(fragments.get(currentIndex));
        if (manager.getFragments().contains(fragment)) {
            transaction.show(fragment);
        } else {
            transaction.add(R.id.main_fragmentFrame, fragment);
        }
        transaction.commit();
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no button to switch tabs! User clicks on a  tab to navigate to that tab.

Comment: In sample code, yes I use a button to show how it works.
Just replace the button with your implementation to catch the user event.

Comment: But switching tabs are catched using  `allTabs.addOnTabSelectedListener` right?

Comment: Yes , listener`s onTabSelected() invoked when user click the tab, It is similar as Button`s onClick().

BTW, you can just add onTabSelectedListener once to tabLayout.
It is no needed to add listener every time create a tab.
The listener is for TabLayout, not just one of tab.

Comment: `fragments.add(newFragment(0));` this creates new fragments right? so in my add button onclick listener i could add this  after creating a tab?

Comment: Yes, you can create Fragment instance after creating tab.
`fragments.add(newFragment(0));` only creates instance not added to FragmentManager yet.

Comment: Creating tab and creating instance of Fragment is two different things.
You can create Fragment instance whenever you want, Just make sure when user click the tab, the Fragment should be available.

Comment: I updated the code as suggested by you.. please have a look. it giving me error. is it the right way to do so? initially, i add a tab and fragment it worked. But when i press add button it shows this error

Comment: Hello.. can you please help me

Comment: I am adding the same fragment on click.. then will this cod work?

Comment: The error is cause by the index you maintain is not correct.
I saw there are numbers of `locfirst = locfirst+1;` might be the problem,
I will update my code with TabLayout.

Comment: If the fragment is exist in FragmentManager, use show()/hide(). It will crash if add same Fragment already added.

Comment: I am creating same fragment multiple time on user input. Is that possible with this code

Comment: Yes, it does. It is possible. The issue of recreating Fragment is resolved. 
Just fix the IndexOutOfBoundsException, and you good to go.
I`ve update the sample code above with TabLayout.

Comment: hello. I added this code. But here, when user add new tab then previously deleted fragment is added. I found that in one fragment I add to list and deleted that fragment and when added new fragment the list is shown in new fragment

Comment: Updated with remove tab function.i removes the tab from fragment

Comment: If you need to control TabLayout in Fragment, you should also maintain the List of Fragment instance and FragmentManager in Fragment too. 

Ex: Remove an tab on `TabLayout`, should also remove reference in `List` and `FragmentManager` by invoking `FragmentManager#remove()`.

It is good to open another question if the original question is resolved.

Answer (score 1):

To save the value only once.. in `timeStamp` in the `shared prefs` just use this in each fragment..

```
@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);

    if (getActivity() == null)
    {

        // generate time stamp in miliseconds as you are doing 
        // and save it in shared prefs 
        // this will be called only once..
    }
}
```

OR YOU CAN TRY IN :-

**UPDATE** `onCreate` of fragmentChild

```
   time= System.currentTimeMillis();
   SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("My_prefs_name",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String timeStamp = sharedPreferences.getString("timeStamp","");

        if ( timeStamp.isEmpty())
        {
            // SAVE TIME IN SHAREPREFS
            sharedPreferences.edit().putString("timeStamp",time).apply();

        }
```

Comment: did you try saving it `onCreateView` instead ?

Comment: Yes.. onCreateView in calling every time when user switch between tabs. onclick it create the same child fragment

Comment: @KarthikCp you can also try one thing.. `if( ! timeStamp_present _in_shared_pref) { save timestamp   }`

Comment: i got it .. use this logic.. as i have updated.. update if it works @KarthikCp if you need help understanding..i will update the answer.. !!

Comment: Can you please update the code so that i  could get a clear picture

Comment: ok ..i will update ..but first post your code.. that you have tried in `onCreate` to save the timestamp in `shared prefs`

Comment: But i need to get the tabPostion as preference key. and timestamp as value, so i could not save prefrence in onCreate. I Just get the time in milliseconds in onCreate and tried to save in onStart. SO i find that onCreate call everytime if i switch tabs. SO that logic fails

Comment: As you can see my FragmentChild onCreate has long time

Comment: Here it is getting preference value right? Where should we set preference value? also the key will not be "timestamp" it will be the current tab position. and we would not get current tab position in onCreate right?

Comment: `get the current tab position` then check and then insert the value if its not empty.. **against the value of current tab position**  @KarthikCp

Comment: in onCreate we could not get tab position. That is where i get stucked

Comment: your bundle isnt giving the current tab position ryt?